# How do you identify what a certain form is using structures in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, forms, data-structures

I have this form named `frmConsult`. And it has two functions. One is for viewing a past record, let us call this "view". The second is for actual data input, called "consult".

My system should allow multiple instances of this form, but not multiple instances of consult. I'm trying to find the right code so that my sub checks if any of the `frmConsult` open is a consult form. And ignores any frmConsult that is a view.

The first `If-Endif` is a code block I found that can check for any forms opened and named `frmConsult`. But I don't know how to differentiate each instance of frmConsult. In this particular setup, I used a structure to give each form it's own variables.

In `frmConsult` I dimmed Consult as xForm. And used `Consult.formType = "View"` or "Consult". I hope this explanation was enough.

```
If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of frmConsult).Any Then
    MsgBox(Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of frmConsult).Any)
End If

Select Case aLevel

    Case "Admin", "Physician"
        sql = "SELECT qstatus from tbl_consult where concat(patientid, '-',consultid)='" & selectedId & "'"
        SelectQuery(cnn, 1)
        If result = "Active" Then
            MsgBox("Updating Queue List")
            fillQueue()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        formSwitch = "Consult"
        Dim Consult = New frmConsult
        Consult.MdiParent = mdiMain
        Consult.Show()

    Case "Secretary"
        If MsgBox("Remove this patient from queue?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Remove") = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        selectedId = dgvQueue.SelectedCells(1).Value.ToString
        sql = "UPDATE tbl_consult set qstatus='Canceled', consultantid = '' where concat(patientid, '-',consultid)='" & selectedId & "'"
        RunQuery(cnn)
End Select

Structure xForm
    Public formType As String
    Public selectedID As String
End Structure
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a `Shared` variable in the `frmConsult` class that you set when there's a consult form open, and clear it when you close the consult form? Something like:

```
Private Shared _consultFormOpen as Boolean = False;
Public Shared Property IsConsultFormOpen() as Boolean
    Get
        return _consuleFormOpen
    End Get
End Property
```

In the form's Show method, or possibly on create, set `_consultFormOpen = True`. And in the Form's Close method, set `_consultFormOpen = False`.

When the user tries to create a new form, you can write:

```
If frmConsult.IsConsultFormOpen Then
    MessageBox.Show("A consult form is already open.")
    ` exit here
End If
```

Comment: My initial idea was to somehow use the structures I've assigned in each form. Unfortunately you can't do this when it's set to private. What you suggested is quite similar to what I'm currently using. Except I didn't go in a round about way for it. I just simply assigned a new boolean specifically for the `frmConsult` if it is of consult type. But still, thanks for your answer, I learned something from this.

Comment: @YinYangKim: I don't know what you mean "a round about way." This technique doesn't require enumerating the existing forms. All you have to do is check a shared property. But you're of course free to implement this whatever way you think is best.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I just meant I didn't have to declare more than the boolean itself, such as `Public Shared Property IsConsultFormOpen() as Boolean`. If I had to describe its algorithm it would be like this: 1. Declare boolean `IsConsultFormOpen` as false 2. Trigger consult type form 3. Check if `IsConsultFormOpen` equals true 4. If true `Exit Sub` else `Open Form` 5. If `frmConsult` loads set `IsConsultFormOpen` to true 6. On closing the form, set to false.